# How to build a cell array of strings containing numbers

Tags: string, matlab

How would you efficiently build a cell array of strings which contain numbers (in my particular case, a cell array of labels for a legend).

Eg:`{'series 1', 'series 2', 'series 3'}`

I've tried things along the lines of

```
sprintf('series %i', {1:10})
```

but apparently sprintf and cell arrays don't play nice together.

Something like this works if I only want the number, but doesn't work if I want text as well.

```
cellstr(int2str([1:10]'))
```

Obviously, it can be done in a loop, but there must be a clever one-liner way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functions [INT2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/int2str.html) and [STRCAT](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/strcat.html) do the trick:

```
>> cellArray = strcat({'series '},int2str((1:3).')).'

cellArray = 

    'series 1'    'series 2'    'series 3'
```

Answer (score 12):

I know it's been 4 years but I came across the undocumented function [sprintfc](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/sprintfc-undocumented-helper-function) which is used to do exactly what you want:

```
CellArray = sprintfc('series %i',1:3);

CellArray = 

    'series 1'    'series 2'    'series 3'
```

well... it might be useful to someone I guess.

Comment: great! Glad someone found out this post :)

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different way:

```
cellArray = cellstr( num2str((1:3)', 'series %d') )
```

or alternatively

```
cellArray = strcat( num2str((1:3)', 'series %d'), {} )
```

with the result:

```
cellArray = 
    'series 1'
    'series 2'
    'series 3'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the one-liner below for more complicated output:

```
cellarray = arrayfun(@(x) {sprintf('item %d of 3', x)}, 1:3)

cellarray = 

    'item 1 of 3'    'item 2 of 3'    'item 3 of 3'
```

Comment: Yes! This! You solved my problem, the other solutions dont work for more involved outputs. I originally made a loop that did not work when used as input for legend():    for ii=1:n;cellArray{ii}={sptrinf('n %d, val %0.2f', ii, vals(ii))};end